# Symfony SonataMediaBundle ClassNotFoundException error during installation

Tags: symfony, sonata-media-bundle

again i have a problem with my first symfony project. I'll try to install SonataMediaBundle. I have install SonataAdminBundle and it works fine. I do everythink with that instruction https://sonata-project.org/bundles/media/3-x/doc/reference/installation.html but in point when i need to add line to AppKernel

```
new Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\ApplicationSonataMediaBundle(),
```

When try to update my database schema i have an error:

Uncaught ClassNotFoundException Ateempted to load class "ApplicationSonataMediaBundle" from namepace "Application\Sonata\MediaBundle". Did you forget to use statement for another namespace? 
In my project/src i have AppBundle and Application directory. Why i have this error? and MediaBundle need ClassificationBundle to work property?

Comment: You just need to adjust the autoload section of composer.json.

Comment: You need to generate YOUR Custom Extended MediaBundle using following command: php app/console sonata:easy-extends:generate --dest=src SonataMediaBundle and register generated Bundle in AppKernel.php

Answer (score 0):

Check if the name of the bundle exist in **composer.json**

```
  "require": {
            "php": ">=5.5.9",
            "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^1.6",
             "yourbundle"
```

Then update composer :

```
php composer.phar update
php composer.phar require
```

Comment: You need to generate YOUR Custom  Extended MediaBundle using following command:
php app/console sonata:easy-extends:generate --dest=src SonataMediaBundle
and register generated Bundle in AppKernel.php

Comment: Yes,that may solve  his issue but i guess he just fixed it and left Stackoverflow